# "java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory cannot be resolved." recurring error in VS Code

Tags: java, string, visual-studio-code

I'm currently making a project and this error pops up on the first line of VS Code whenever I use lines such as this:

```
return "UserProfile{" +
                "userName='" + playerName + '\'' +
                ", numKalahGamesPlayed=" + kalahPlayed +
                ", numAyoGamesPlayed=" + ayoPlayed +
                ", numKalahGamesWon=" + kalahGamesWon +
                ", numAyoGamesWon=" + ayoGamesWon +
                '}';
```

This error always pops up and doesn't go away until I use something other than the '+' key in System.out.println messages.

This error just appears and doesn't affect the functionality of the code and doesn't stop me from doing "gradle build" but is annoying to look at.

My program is in Java and I've already refreshed/restarted VS Code and I've clean the Java lang workspace multiple times but nothing works. I know that StringBuilder works and I know how to use it but it's much easier to use System.out.println();

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: This error usually occurs when you're using a Java version that's lower than Java 9. What version of java are you using?

Comment: exactly what JDK are you using and what version of it? how did you configure intellisense?

Comment: @starball
I'm currently using Java 8 and I checked for updates and there aren't any (Update 391 to be specific) I don't know how my intellisense is supposed to be configured since I don't remember touching settings related to that, at all. I'm using Docker to run Java if that helps clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

Set compiler compliance level to Java 1.8.